# Deploy NodeJS/MongoDB application. Where and how?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I’ve finished working on my node application which provide a series of APIs endpoint for a mobile application. I’ve made it with node and mongodb as db. Now I’ve reached the point where I should pick the right deployment environment.
Initially I’ll make a private beta but I need to choose a service I can scale easily (I’m not a devop) with the right price balance.
My initial choice is amazon aws (elastic beanstalk?). What’s about the db? I’ve not used dynamodb in order to be more service agnostic but now I don’t know how to create a reliable db infrastructure. Any suggestion to deploy both app and dB in order to make easy scaling in case it will become necessary?

Comment: try https://zeit.co/ or https://www.heroku.com/ , getting started with both these is very easy and don not require complex devops work

Comment: I am using Heroku for my nodejs based apps. Very happy with it.

Comment: Heroku might be a little easier as it's mostly configured through the UI and a mongodb is only a click away to add as a plugin.  Warning, on the free plan the program will pause after 30 minutes of no use

Comment: Heroku's pricing is horrible once you app grows, it's only good for quick PoCs. I would recommend OpenShift which is free up to 3 apps and will provide good scalability (it's kubernetes-based) - but it implies you have some knowledge in Docker.